# How to make a textbox clickable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

can anyone help how to make a `textbox` clickable while it is a in `readonly` state.

I want to do is a can click my textboxes just like a button because i have plans to it.

```
<input type="text" readonly value="Click me" id="clickme" />
```

Comment: is always in readonly mode?

Comment: If you want to do things with it why are you setting `readonly` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, **readonly** catch click, **disabled** doesen't . [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMp9z/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').on('click', function(){
        alert(1)
    })    
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
  // logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" readonly value="Click me" id="clickme" onClick="myFunction()"/>


<script>
    ...
    function myFunction(){
        // Your function
    }
    ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a click event to the textbox.

**JQuery:**

```
$("#clickme").click(function(){
alert("do something");
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WjRJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery is awesome if you include it.

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function(e) {
   // do something 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Without more information as to what, precisely, you want to do, I'd suggest:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function(){
    // to allow for editing of contents:
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5Pqdb/).

Or:

```
$('#clickme').on('click', function(){
    // to do something if this is readonly:
    if (this.readOnly) {
        // for example:
        console.log('this input is readonly');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5Pqdb/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery as

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
 alert('clickable');
// Your Method.
});
```

Add few style too

```
#clickme
{
cursor:pointer;
cursor:hand;
}
```

Check out this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/WGZkP/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use onclick function, like

```
    <input type="text" readonly value="Click me" id="clickme" onclick="myfunction()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){
  alert('Textbox is clicked)
});
```